# Does negation only affect variables?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Does negation only affect variables or does it affect connectives too?

E.g.

Would $\lnot (a \lor b)$ be the same as

This:
$(\lnot a \lor \lnot b)$

Or would it be the same as this:
$(\lnot a \land \lnot b)$

And if it *is* the second one, then what other connectives would be affected by a negation apart from conjunction ($ \land $) and disjunction ($ \lor $) and how would they be delt with?

Comment: The *negation* sign applies to **formulae**.

Comment: Formulae are : either *(i)* *atomic*, i.e. (propositional) *variables* : $p, q, \ldots$, or *(ii)* "complex" ones, like $(p \lor q), \lnot p, \ldots$.

Comment: You ask if $\lnot (a \lor b)$ is the same as $(\lnot a \lor \lnot b)$. Have you tried to mak the truth table for these expressions to see if they *are* equal, or anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The negation sign applies to *formulae*.

Formulae are : either *(i)* atomic, i.e. (propositional) *variables*: $p,q,\ldots$, or *(ii)* "complex" ones, like: $(p∨q),¬p,\ldots$

The formula $¬(a∨b)$ is equivalent to : $¬a ∧ ¬b$; see [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws#Negation_of_a_disjunction).

Similarly: $¬a ∨ ¬b$ is equivalent to $¬(a ∧ b)$.

Comment: I think that's the truth value of those two end up as equivalent, not the formulae.

Comment: See [Logical equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence) : "In logic, statements $p$ and $q$ are *logically equivalent* if they have the same logical content. Two statements are equivalent if they have the same truth value in every model." The truth values are not "equivalent" : they are the same.